Make two-column nomenclature like the usual Index
I am trying to use nomencl to create an Index of Symbols with two columns.
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,bm,stmaryrd} 
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}

\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, \hyperpage{#1}}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Index of Symbols}
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}\vfill}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{1.5cm}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{g}$\nomenclature{$\mathfrak{g}$}{Lie algebra of $G$}
$\mathfrak{h}$\nomenclature{$\mathfrak{h}$}{Lie algebra of $H$}
$\mathfrak{p}$\nomenclature{$\mathfrak{p}$}{a prime ideal}
$K$\nomenclature{$K$}{a field}
$T_pM$\nomenclature{$T_pM$}{the tangent space of $M$ at $p$}

\newpage
\printnomenclature

\end{document}


However, what I want looks like this:


Namely, I expect the Index of Symbols behaves like the usual Index:
(1) It starts with a new column only if the first column is full.
(2) For the second column, I don't want them to separate to fill the vertical space equally.
(3) I can use a command like \index{G@\mathfrak{g}} to sort the symbols according to alphabets, and there are small vertical space between different groups (e.g. there is a small space between A-group and B-group).


You're almost there: just use multicols*. And no \vfill.
However, note the changes I made to your preamble: load packages first and do settings later. Also \linespread{1.1} is better than redefining \baselinestretch.
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,bm,stmaryrd} 
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, \hyperpage{#1}}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Index of Symbols}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{%
  \setlength{\columnsep}{3em}%
  \begin{multicols*}{2}%
}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols*}}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{1.5cm}%

\makenomenclature

\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{g}$\nomenclature{$\mathfrak{g}$}{Lie algebra of $G$}
$\mathfrak{h}$\nomenclature{$\mathfrak{h}$}{Lie algebra of $H$}
$\mathfrak{p}$\nomenclature{$\mathfrak{p}$}{a prime ideal}
$K$\nomenclature{$K$}{a field}
$T_pM$\nomenclature{$T_pM$}{the tangent space of $M$ at $p$}

\count255=`a
\loop
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \begingroup\lccode`?=\count255
  \lowercase{\nomenclature{w??}{???}}
  \lowercase{\nomenclature{z??}{???}}
  \ifnum\count255<`z
\repeat

\clearpage

\printnomenclature

\end{document}

The code from \count255 to \repeat is just to produce mock nomenclature entries to show the final effect.


Thanks a lot!! Moreover, I wonder how to solve my Q3. In your demonstration (and also mine), $\mathfrak{p}$ is in front of $K$. However, $K$ should be in front of $\mathfrak{p}$ according to lexicographic order. In addition, how to add some space between different alphabetical groups?
